# Custom week for static fiscal year

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create logic for custom weeks in a fiscal year that always starts on Jan 1st, and ends on Dec 31st. I was able to get the correct week numbers for each month, but can't customize the weeks correctly for the year. For instance, the data still shows week 53 for the first two days of January 2016. In short, Week 1 should start on 1/1/yyyy and week 52 or 53 (in some cases) end on 12/31/yyyy.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

L

Comment: which sql database and where's your sql statement?

Comment: This is for SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL

```
SELECT CEILING(DAYOFYEAR('your date') / 7)
```

POSTGRES

```
SELECT CEILING(EXTRACT('DOY' FROM DATE 'your date') / 7)
```

ORACLE

```
SELECT CEIL(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDD') / 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
you can replace @YourDate with the date you wanted to check

```
SELECT DATEPART( wk, @YourDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added that code, but got the same results as before. The issue is that Week 1 always starts on 1/1/yyyy, but if you look at the screen print, it actually starts in Dec 28, 2015. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I believe this might help simplify the solution. Thanks